# Error al instalar sbt para play framework java (openjdk-8-jdk dependencias incumplidas)

Tags: java, java-8, playframework

Recientemente instale `oracle-java8-installer` y al ejecutar

```
java -version
```

me devolvia: java version "1.8.0_121" por lo que intuyo que todo esta bien. Para instalar jdk 8 segui los pasos del [siguiente enlace](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html)

Para instalar sbt (para programar en play framework) segui los pasos de la documentacion oficial:

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp: //keyserver.ubuntu.com: 80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> sbt: Depende de: openjdk-8-jdk pero no es instalable

y cuando intento

```
apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

me dice que

> el paquete no tiene cadidato para su instalación.

He intentado descargar el paquete .deb para sbt pero me muestra el mismo error de dependencia.

Lo unico que necesito es instalar sbt, sin embargo el error de dependencia con `openjdk-8-jdk` me lo impide. Alguien podria darme alguna sugerencia.

Answer (score 2):

Pude solucionarlo, dado que uso debian 8 la solucion fue desisntalar oracle-java8-installer y reinstalarlo de los repositorios backports de debian 8.

```
apt-get remove oracle-java8-installer

echo 'deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list

apt install -t jessie-backports openjdk-8-jre-headless ca-certificates-java openjdk-8-jdk

update-java-alternatives --set java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

java -version ahora me devuelve openjdk version "1.8.0_121"

y finalmente seguir los pasos oficiales para instalar sbt.